# While building JMeter script in Jenkins,encountered following error: 'CannotResolveClassException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector'

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-pipeline

I've been working on building a JMX file (JMeter) from Jenkins for many days now. Suddenly, I encountered an error that says 'CannotResolveClassException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector'

Answer (score 0):

It means that your test is using some [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) and a plugin or one of its dependencies is not installed, in particular you need to have [jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter) in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

1. Install clean latest JMeter
2. Install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)
3. Open your test plan
4. Plugins manager will detect used plugins and suggest installing them
5. Install these plugins on JMeter used in Jenkins

Comment: i tried but still dint work, getting below in console (my jmx file is in git also, from my local command line works fine)                     outputError in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/tools/testingenvcheckout/devperftest/src/test/java/com/nextenture/jemter-performance-test/DEV_Performance_smoke_Test_V3.jmx'. 
Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector

Comment: You need to install the plugin **on Jenkins**